# Initial seeds for k-means from hierarchical clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

So I have about one million rows and I need to cluster them. I started with drawing a random sample and calculate hierarchical clusters to obtain the dendogram. With this I have the idea how many clusters there are.

Now I would like to use K-Means clustering on the whole sample with initial seeds from the previous step - hierarchical clustering. But I dont know how obtain those initial seeds.

Below code for hierarchical clustering:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage
from sklearn import preprocessing as prep

seed = 85
df_s = df.sample(frac=0.01, replace=False)
df_s = df_s.reset_index(drop=True)

scaler = prep.MinMaxScaler()

df_std = scaler.fit_transform(df_s[clmns])

Z = linkage(df_std, 'ward')
```

Then for the K-Means, I know i can call it as follows:

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2
centroid, label = kmeans2(df[clmns], 3)
```

I know that argument `minit` is to insert n x p matrix with the seeds, but it is not clear to me how to obtain them.

*This question was originally posted on cross-validation. But since it is more about programming, it was recommended to me to post it here.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since hierarchical clustering is not centroid-based,

1. you have to compute the cluster centroid yourself (easy)
2. the clusters found by hierarchical clustering may be a rather bad starting point for k-means

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why it is a bad starting point for k-means ? We are thinking of doing this for our clustering : sampling ==> hierarchical to find centroids ==> kmeans

Comment: Just do sampling => k-means on sample then use the sample centroids as starting point for the full k-means run. This will be both faster, and better. That is roughly what Fayyad et al. suggested, if I recall correctly, and one of the best strategies.

Comment: But if you just need to speed up k-means, check for faster implementations. Here is a recent comparision: Kriegel, H. P. et al. (2016). The (black) art of runtime evaluation: Are we comparing algorithms or implementations?. Knowledge and Information Systems, 1-38. — apparently, there are huge performance differences.